# MSDataShape error, broken on upgrade to Windows 10 Feature Update 1809

Tags: vba, windows, vb6, adodb, recordset

In our VB6 application, we use ADODB.Recordsets and make use of the Data provider for MSDataShape to create a relational recordset with SHAPE commands.

In the latest Windows 10 Feature (1809) our code breaks with the following error: -

> "-2147217900 Length of NEW column SiteCode cannot be zero"

from the following macro in excel (where MDAC is a reference)

```
Public Sub TestRun()
    Dim rsStockCheck As Recordset

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' set up shape recordset
    Set rsStockCheck = New Recordset
    With rsStockCheck
        .ActiveConnection = "Provider=MSDataShape;Data Provider=None"
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
        .Open "SHAPE APPEND new adInteger as StockCheckID, new adInteger as SiteID, new adVarChar(8) as SiteCode"
        .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End With

ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "failed: " & Err.Description
    Else
        MsgBox "works ok"
    End If

    Set rsStockCheck = Nothing
End Sub
```

This might be related to this being eventually removed [as mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-data-shaping-service-for-ole-db-ado-service-provider).

... but I'm not sure if it is just yet. Has anyone come across this problem?

---

**EDIT**: I've tried this on an upgraded machine and Fresh install of 1809 and it's broken on both.

---

**EDIT 2**: List of other forum threads regarding this issue:

- [*Microsoft "Data Platform Development > ADO.NET DataSet" forum*](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2705acfa-46c7-4d30-b10b-26b043591c6f/please-read-problem-with-ado-amp-vachar-in-windows-10-update-1809-and-server-2019?forum=adodotnetdataset:)
  (Reported by someone else, and it affects Server 2019 too)
- [*Microsoft "Windows Desktop Development > General Windows Desktop Development Issues" forum*](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/761db77c-2309-4fd1-a169-eb20b34fda31/msdatashape-broken-on-upgrade-to-windows-10-feature-update-1809?referrer=https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/761db77c-2309-4fd1-a169-eb20b34fda31/msdatashape-broken-on-upgrade-to-windows-10-feature-update-1809?referrer=https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/761db77c-2309-4fd1-a169-eb20b34fda31/msdatashape-broken-on-upgrade-to-windows-10-feature-update-1809?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)
- [*Microsoft "Windows 10 IT Pro > Windows 10 Insider Preview Builds" forum*](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3c855e42-90f4-4a76-9fb9-8be16bb815fa/ado-amp-varchar?forum=WindowsInsiderPreview#af96b79b-e9f4-45e6-95e4-00633a3dacb6)
- *[Microsoft " Windows Server Windows > Server Insiders" forum](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Server-Insiders/ADO-amp-VARCHAR/td-p/264369)*

**EDIT 3**: Latest Nov 13 update for Windows 1809, still does not fix this issue. **For a workaround however, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53309908/431569)**.

Comment: Same issue here, any suggestion?

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing the same issue. I do notice that appending a `NEW adBSTR AS SomeColumn` still works.

Comment: interesting that adBSTR still works, might a potential workaround.

Comment: I didn't find any mention of this problem on MS's Feedback Hub, so I filed a report: https://aka.ms/AA2qru1 (not sure if there's a better place to report Windows bugs)

Comment: Thanks Dave, it's fairly new and customers should be testing their applications before applying it to client machines so it's probably not there yet.

Comment: @DaveHuang, I've done a virtual chat to MS this morning. That place is where to log it and they've said to keep an eye on it for updates.

Comment: @DaveHuang When I click the link   aka.ms/AA2qru1   it just open a new (empty) report. Does this mean that I need to open my own report in the MS Feedback Hub? Because I don't understand how I'm supposed to "keep an eye on it for updates".

Comment: @Max, I just tried to view the issue that Dave raised... it seems to have been removed! :(

Comment: Raised another one: feedback-hub:?contextid=158&feedbackid=6d1322ed-e271-4c5e-8169-e528437d715a&form=1&src=1

Comment: even the new link (now) open a new empty report... bizarre... :-|

Comment: about my last comment, maybe it's a connection issue on my PC. Now it tell me that I need to login with an MS account to do anything with Feedback hub.. i'll do some check on my MS account

Comment: @Max Both feedback hub link I posted and the new one from Max Power are still working for me.

Comment: FYI, the latest hotfix from MS does not solve this issue still (was released 9th): KB4464330

Comment: Is this a VB6 or VBA issue?

Comment: @DaveInCaz, both.

Comment: I've added a workaround in my original post, however the bug exists and can't see it being fixed soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Shrikant has mentioned, this was fixed in a recent windows update (Version: 1809 OS Build : 17763.475) and also confirm it's fixed in 1903.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem with me ... However, I have found the workaround for this issue ...
Replacing adVarChar(##) with adLongVarChar does the job for me ...

Please reply, if anyone has another solution

Edited:
This workaround is not applicable to queries like

```
SHAPE APPEND NEW adLongVarChar As INVNO, NEW adLongVarChar As iCP,
((SHAPE APPEND NEW aadLongVarChar As INVNO,NEW adLongVarCharAs iCP,NEW adLongVarChar As F1,NEW adLongVarChar As F2,NEW adLongVarChar As F3)
AS Trans RELATE INVNO TO INVNO,iCP TO iCP)
```

Finding a solution to get out of this issue

**EDIT : This error has been fixed in recent windows update (Version: 1809 OS Build : 17763.475).** Everything working fine for me.

Comment: Its certainly a viable workaround, although I wonder if this is a Microsoft Bug generally as the error suggests no parameter provided. I am hoping that the feedback log submitted from Dave yields a response from Microsoft.

Comment: I'd use adLongVarWChar, but in principle it is the same.  It's a hack but it may be the only option we ever get.

Comment: @Bob77, as Shrikant said though, it doesn't fully work, so I'm hoping they do fix it!

Comment: @Shrikant, did you ever work around the issue you found with doing this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that works in all scenarios.

Instead of `adVarChar(size)` use the OLEDB datatype `DBTYPE_BSTR`. For example, instead:

```
SHAPE APPEND NEW adVarChar(8) As INVNO, NEW adVarChar(8) As iCP,
((SHAPE APPEND NEW adVarChar(8) As INVNO,NEW adVarChar(8) As iCP...)
AS Trans RELATE INVNO TO INVNO,iCP TO iCP)
```

write:

```
SHAPE APPEND NEW DBTYPE_BSTR As INVNO, NEW DBTYPE_BSTR As iCP,
((SHAPE APPEND NEW DBTYPE_BSTR As INVNO,NEW DBTYPE_BSTR As iCP...)
AS Trans RELATE INVNO TO INVNO,iCP TO iCP)
```

**Notes:**

1. **DBTYPE_BSTR** doesn't accept the size of the field, so it's not exactly a varchar
2. I had to use **DBTYPE_BSTR** keyword, using **adBSTR** produced an error message in the command (?!).

Comment: It's a decent workaround, is there much more memory usage using these fields? I think long term, it would be best to move away from MSDataShape. It's what we're doing now and our solution using XML files to create structures and populate them from SQL XML output.

Comment: If there is any more memory usage it's hard to notice. The program shows now measurable increase.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, MSDataShape is obsolete and being removed.

Suggest that you port your queries to `FROM XML` and change your client to parse the response using SAX or a pull parser.

Comment: Could you provide an example please for a ported one from Shrikant's answer above)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems changing `SHAPE APPEND new adVarChar(8) as SiteCode` to 
`SHAPE APPEND new adLongVarChar as SiteCode` causes that SiteCode can not be a sort key.

However it seems SiteCode_Calc of `SHAPE APPEND new adLongVarChar as SiteCode,calc(Left$(SiteCode,8)) as SiteCode_Calc` can be a sort key.

However it seems MoveNext/EOF won't work correctly when the value of SiteCode_Calc is gotten.

Comment: Worth a try... shame really though. For myself, I've had to work around it by saving out the structures to an XML file then loading them back in from that instead of using MSDataShape.